# Sitecore Out of Box Personalization not working

Tags: personalization

We are using OKTA authentication for the sitecore client facing website and there are few attributes defined on users profile in OKTA portal and we are building Virtual users and adding those Attributes to the created users and assigning roles to them accordingly.

*Example we have a role created in Sitecore as extranet\Admin, we have an Attribute named 'IsAdmin' for the user in OKTA Portal, so checking this flag we enable the extranet\Admin role to the virtual user we create.*

In the Personalization rule - We are checking if the current user is part of that role using the below predefined rule "Where the current user is a member of specific (in this occasion extranet/admin) role and personalizing based on this. This doesn't seem to work but we can see all the properties getting assigned properly to the context user and this is happening in Sitecore 9.3 website but the same was working in our Sitecore 8.2 website. We have done an upgrade from 8.2 to 9.3.

We are not seeing any errors in the log, are there any issues with the predefined personalization rules of Sitecore under Security bracket which deals with current user context anyone aware of? Any suggestions/thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Is all personalization broken or just this case? Also, did you install XM or XP packages?

Comment: Personalization based on user role, user profile fields seems to be broken but we tried with other fields like data, month of the year it worked. This is happening in our Sitecore  managed cloud environments.

Answer (score 1):

We've stepped into something similar during 9.0 -> 9.3 upgrade:

**TL;DR**: New personalization does not show up for all visitors by default.

- [Personalization effect tracking](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--personalizing-components.html) checkbox (personalize the component, bottom left) is selected by default for newly created personalization rules; [it allocates only a part of the audience to track the effect](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/personalization-effect-tracking.html).

**TL;DR**: Condition logic/class might have changed. This can be checked via [iLSpy or dotPeek](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Debugging-framework-internals-without-source-code).

- Breaking changes in rules: both conditions and rule actions are identified by rule item id. That ID is embedded/saved inside the item layout field, and parsed/located on fly. In between versions (9.0 -> 9.3) we detected ~10 broken/changed definitions, therefore all items using those rules got personalization broken as well.